# What is the radius of convergence for the taylor series for $\frac{\sin(x)}{1-x}$ expanded at 0

Tags: real-analysis

Using the Cauchy product I found that $\beta=\lim|\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ (if I remember correctly), and thought this was equivalent to the radius of convergence of $\sin(x)$, but that doesn't seem logical since the original function isn't even defined at $x=1$. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: The series' denominator should be $(2k+1)!$.

Comment: In this case it's better to use the ratio test, which gives 1 as the limit, and hence the radius of convergence.

Comment: @Chrystomath of course, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence is the distance from the center of the expansion to the nearest singularity, which would be $1$. This distance is $|1-0|=1$, so the radius of convergence is $1$.